# NavigationView Hamburger button style

Tags: navigationview, uno-platform

I am working on an app that uses a navigationview.  I updated Uno to the latest prerelease(Uno 3.0.0-dev.405)- and today after updating Uno, the Hamburger button/Toggle button no longer has the same color as the rest of the menuitems- it is black.  I added in the PaneButtonStyle - but that did not work either.  How do I fix this?

```
<NavigationView x:Name="NavView"
                  Loaded="NavView_Loaded"
                  ItemInvoked="NavView_ItemInvoked"
                  PaneDisplayMode="LeftCompact" IsPaneOpen="False"
                  IsBackButtonVisible="Collapsed"
                  BackRequested="NavView_BackRequested"
                  Foreground="{StaticResource NavigationViewItemForeground}"
                  Background="{StaticResource NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground}"
                  PaneToggleButtonStyle="{StaticResource PaneToggleButtonColor}" 
                  Grid.Row="1"   >
```

Style- in separate Resource Dictionary:

```
        <Color x:key="PaneToggleButtonColor">#FF0A8000</Color>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewDefaultPaneBackground" Color="#FFF2F2F2"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForeground" Color="Green"/>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundSelected" Color="Green"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPointerOver" Color="Green"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundPressed" Color="Green"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewItemForegroundSelectedPressed" Color="Green"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationViewSelectionIndicatorForeground"  Color="DarkOrange" />
```

Comment: One additional point- if I revert to 3.0.0-dev.179 it works as expected- setting the Hamburger Menu to green.

Comment: I think you might be better reporting this as an issue [here](https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues) and using the version that works for you until it's fixed.

Comment: Of course, you could also look at the commits between 3.0.0-dev.179 and 3.0.0-dev.405 to see which change introduced the issue and then submit a PR to fix it :0)

Comment: There was a huge style and theme-related PR merged, which is most likely the reason things work differently. Does your implementation work correctly on UWP?

Comment: Well- unfortunately it seems I will need to stick on 179 for now.  It seems to work consistently across all platforms- so as ibebbs and Martin Zikmund pointed out- there was a huge style and theme related merge.  I will comb through the changes to see if I can single out the issue and if I can submit a PR.  I appreciate the comments and help.

Comment: 'Consistently across all platforms' - 179 is consistent, or 405 is consistent?